# Советы по highload для начинающих

Tags: highload, php

Сабж. Прошу любых советов, от того, как надо строить архитектуру приложения, до того, какие сервера лучше использовать с какими примочками

Comment: Если речь о новичке и о php - начни со знакомства с никсами

Comment: @AlexWindHope, Ubuntu подойдёт?

Comment: Т.к. с чего-то надо начинать - конечно

Comment: "highload" и "начинающих" (в общем плане, а не начинающий в плане "разработки проектов с высокой нагрузкой") ну никак не совмещаются в одном приложении.

Для практики очень хорошо взять какую то тормозную cms и пробывать её оптимизировать.

Comment: @shurik, ну в принципе для "начинающих в highload".  
Спасибо за совет про CMS.

Comment: Понекрофильствую

ruhighload.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос очень обширный, и его лучше разделить на несколько вопросов:

- оптимизация и настройка серверной части
- оптимизация и масштабирование приложений

Я бы рекоммендовал ознакомиться с общими понятиями и опытом "крупных" ребят в highload'e:

- [Худшие практики масштабирования](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/04/20/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/)
- [Опыт масштабирования Твиттера](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/12/03/twitter-architecture-and-scaling/)
- [Блог highscalability](http://highscalability.com/)